Как вызвать функцию из файла C/C++ в NASM?
Решил написать операционную систему (без глобальных целей, просто как проект для души и практики) и задался глобальным вопросом. Не хочу в начале долго останавливаться на ассемблере. Языками выбрал NASM и C++. Теперь главный вопрос: как вызвать из .asm загрузчика функцию, которая находится в .cpp файле ядра? Должен ли я использовать linker или что-то другое?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Обычно загрузчик и ядро это 2 независимых файла и загрузчик после необходимой инициализации аппаратуры прямо передает управление (например, делает jmp) на точку входа загруженного им кода ядра и не использует никакие функции из файла ядра.

Да, нужен linker, nasm с "-f elf" аргументами и использование extern "C" в коде c++ для вызова функций из asm кода. Внутри функций которые как extern "C" уже можно вызывать плюсы. Иначе метки функций, допустим, класса, будут иметь имена типа _ZN1a3fooEv, а из asm файла мы делаем call foo (foo != _ZN1a3fooEv). У c++ другая компиляция, поэтому надо изворачиваться для связывания.
